# Hidden build.xml in google play services library used for google maps v2?

Tags: android

I believe eclipse had a case of the crashes and something weird happened. I restarted the project and have done everything I can think of from scratch.

The code and config files look perfect.

++I have updated the project via command line. (`./android update project --name GPSTest --target 4 --path "/home/me/workspace/GPSTest"`)

++I then go to the root of the project and use `ant debug`

and I get this error:

```
-build-setup:
[echo] Resolving Build Target for GPSTest...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Google APIs
[gettarget] Vendor:           Google Inc.
[gettarget] Platform Version: 4.2
[gettarget] API level:        17
[echo] ----------
[echo] Creating output directories if needed...
[echo] ----------
[echo] Resolving Dependencies for GPSTest...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------
[dependency] Ordered libraries:
[echo] ----------
[echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...

BUILD FAILED
/home/me/android-sdks/tools/ant/build.xml:595: 
Invalid file: /home/me/android-sdks/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject
/google-play-services_lib/build.xml
```

I have no idea how this happened

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try running android update project on the play services lib.

Beyond that, I would delete google_play_services and get a fresh copy from the Android SDK manager.

Comment: This did not create a build.xml file in the google play services folder.

Answer (score 30):

Running

```
android update project --path .
```

on the google_play_services directory fixed this exact problem for me.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `lib-project` instead of `project`?

Comment: It also needs --target param, which can be obtained by `android list targets`.

Comment: feel free to edit my response if you like, in my case the above command worked without any other parameters.

Comment: mine needed --target param as well.  Still no luck, not sure what that should be

Comment: `android update lib-project --target 8 --path .` did it for me.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you don't have a build.xml file google-play-services_lib folder

To create that file you need to Go to the system SK Directory

```
$SDK_HOME/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib and run "android update project -p ./ --target 20"
```

Change the target as needed.